# Regex - Extract third number from string using powershell

Tags: html, powershell, powershell-4.0

This is a one-liner fixed string from HTTP respond.
The numbers in this string are dynamic:

```html
<tr><td>Sum</td><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>132</td><td> </td><td>35</td><td>465</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>42</td></tr>
```

I need to extract the third number (in this case `132`) with regex.
Can someone explain how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conceptually simplest approach is to  use the **[`[regex]::Matches()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Matches_System_String_System_String_)** .NET method with a simple `\d+` regex to find *all* (non-negative decimal) numbers in the input string, and use *indexing* to get the match of interest (`[2]` returns the 3rd match):

```bash
$str = '<tr><td>Sum</td><td>10</td><td>0</td><td>132</td><td> </td><td>35</td><td>465</td><td>0</td><td>56</td><td>42</td></tr>'

# -> '132'
[regex]::Matches(
  $str,
  '\d+'
).Value[2]
```

---

If you're willing to use a more complex regex, you can use the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator:

```bash
# -> '132'
$str -replace '^.+?\d+.+?\d+.+?(\d+).*$', '$1'
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/pVCWgp/1).